# Short story about 'sloppy luck' elves

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title or author of a short story about a person who has good luck elves living in a birdcage or something like that. He disturbs them;  they move out and sloppy elves move in and give him sloppy luck.  This would have been written somewhere in the 50's, I believe. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The story is "Housing Problem" by Henry Kuttner, published in 1944 and originally collected in '[The Best of Henry Kuttner](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Best-Henry-Kuttner/dp/034524415X)'

[image: The Best of Henry Kuttner]

There's a complete (and I assume copyright-friendly given the age) version online [here](http://xn----7sbb3aiknde1bb0dyd.xn--p1ai/new/index.php?id=132856&pages=1).

The tagline for the story was

> "**What if your tenants paid rent in "luck" rather than cash?**"

[image: Housing Problem]

Comment: Huh, is that the [robot from "Piggy Bank"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177750/short-story-about-a-process-for-synthetic-diamonds-a-robot-engineered-for-escap) on the cover?