# Short story about a process for synthetic diamonds, a robot engineered for escape, and a betrayal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I think I read this somewhere in the 1990s in Ashland, KY, from a book checked out in the library. The basic premise is that two scientists (engineers?) find a way to grow large synthetic diamonds. I want to say that it involved an extension of a known method involving a blow-torch and carbonized steel (I'm more certain of the blowtorch part) that normally only produced small ones used for things like grinding surfaces. Anyhow, they figure out this secret, and decide they need a good way of hiding it until they can capitalize on their discovery. They decide to hide it in a robot, said robot for some reason studded with the diamonds they'd built (advertising?). They make a point about how a true thinking brain takes up a space the size of a building, but they figure they can provide enough animal cunning for escape in something more humanoid. This is successful, with the robot evading many attempts to capture it (I want to say one involved them attempting to trap the robot against a very low-friction surface, possibly caused by an oil slick, and it basically toboggans its way across on its front).

> One of the two scientists gets kidnapped and tortured for the code to deactivate the robot, but refuses and dies. We eventually find out that it was the other scientist who'd ordered him kidnapped, because he wanted the process and the money all to himself. Eventually, he realizes he's not going to win, and also realizes what his partner's passcode is, the designation of the closed patent they'd filed, allowing everyone to access the information there and make their own diamonds.

In retrospect, it might have been the diamonds on the robot that were the prize, not a method stored away in it. Maybe said diamonds were necessary to fund the equipment to do the process on an industrial scale.

Comment: Libraries hold withdrawal records going back decades. Why not call them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Piggy Bank](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46552) by Henry Kuttner. I'd wager you read it in the anthology [A Treasury of Great Science Fiction](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?1315), a mainstay of libraries and the Science Fiction Book Club.

[image]

The robot is supposed to be the ultimate safe to hold the synthetic diamonds because it can run away or sound an alarm when someone tries to crack it open.  It's studded with synthetic diamonds because the synthetic diamond tycoon "likes ostentation."

The plot's a bit convoluted: The person who built the robot (different from the synthetic diamond tycoon) built in a dead-man code: he had to change a setting on the robot every so often or his password resets. The tycoon doesn't know this, and kills the inventor.  Then he has to figure out how to reclaim the diamonds.  But...

> the inventor had set the password to the formula for the synthetic diamonds, so the tycoon has to yell it out, in earshot of everyone, to shut down the robot.  This lets his secret out and ruins him.

Comment: It took me a little while to track this down.  I thought it was in "The Best of Henry Kuttner", it wasn't, and I had to run down my list of old anthologies.  I couldn't remember the title, but knew it was by Kuttner.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The rocket on the left edge of the spine is actually the front of a rocket whose rear is on the spine of volume 1.

Comment: @Buzz yes, and they switched the black and white colors on the two volumes.  A memorable design!

Comment: I remember that, as a child, I thought it was a hand with very long pink fingernails. :-D